# How to use common method for example AddUser with domain objects OldVersionProject.User and NewVersionProject.User

Tags: c#, dll, assemblies

I mean that I have two objects for which number of variables and names completely the same with only 1 difference that they are stored in two different assemblies.

Is it possible to mark somehow the dll that it is the same objects, so I could use "User" object from the old project and "User" from the new project with the same common service AddUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is screaming out for an interface

```
namespace OldVersionProject
{
    public class User : IUser
    {
    }
}

namespace NewVersionProject
{
    public class User : IUser
    {
    }
}

public interface IUser
{
    // common properties
}
```

Then in your common service

```
public void AddUser(IUser user)
{
    // user is now version independant
}
```

Comment: Yeah.. I was thinking about this. I think this is the best answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Extract the `User` class into a shared library, say, `BusinessObjects`, and reference that library from all projects that need a `User` class.

Comment: There are 2 versions of `User` though, that's the problem - they are clashing.

Comment: @James that does not make my answer wrong. It is a problem that _can_ be solved by removing the `User` class from both projects if all they do is share a few properties and act like a DTO, and stick one class in a shared library. It only depends on how much code you wish to change.

Comment: If I re-worded the question to be "*I have multiple versions of a `User` class which I need to support in a common method*" would you still answer the same? That's pretty much how I read it...I guess that's the beauty of SO - people have different interpretations on things.

Comment: @James I don't say an interface isn't an option, but that's the answer you've already given. I am biased because I read _"common service `AddUser()`"_ in the question, I'd rather even suggest to swap out or map to a `CreateUser` DTO. I don't think there's enough information to select any of our answers as 'best', let alone there being a 'wrong' one. :-)